# Android mediaPlayer setDataSource failed giving IOException

Tags: java, android

The problem is quite weird. The problem is that whenever I try to name the file with String of timestamp, the setDataSource method fails giving IOException but if I give name such as containing alphabets like "Hello.m4a", it works without any problem.

**The following code gives Error:**

java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.

```
outputFile =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Notes/Audio/AUD_";

private String getTimeStamp() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();


    return new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmmss",Locale.ENGLISH).format(calendar.getTimeInMillis())+".m4a";


}
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(outputFile+getTimeStamp());
mediaPlayer.prepare();
```

**The following code works fine**

```
outputFile =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Notes/Audio/AUD_";

private String getTimeStamp() {
    return "hello.m4a"
}

mediaPlayer.setDataSource(outputFile+getTimeStamp());
mediaPlayer.prepare();
```

I want to name the files with Timestamp to structure the files easily.

Answer (score 2):

[`setDataSource(String path)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#setDataSource(java.lang.String))
sets the data source (file-path) to use.

The path to the file **must not be null**.
Otherwise you get an error - in your case an `IOException`.

Also you are trying to access a file that doesn't exist. The expression

```java
SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmmss",Locale.ENGLISH).format(calendar.getTimeInMillis())+".m4a"
```

creates a string with the current time which doesn't exist in your directory.

You should pass the exact file path.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Michael :) I edited your answer a bit to highlight the important parts - if you feel i edited too much please do a rollback

Comment: Happy to help Ali Asad

Answer (score 0):

You need to have permission to read/write external storage, in order to do this.